# Extra information in DateTime property

Tags: python, datetime, google-cloud-datastore

When i try to access time property it gives me value like this "**2014-11-30 16:36:39.244140**"
What this last extra number means (**244140**)?

```
 class Employee(db.Model):
      time= db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, they are Python `datetime` objects, stored in UTC time.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#DateTimeProperty

And if you look at the documentation on `datetime.datetime`, you will see that those 'extra numbers' are the microseconds.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for it, but i couldn't find it.